# How to get value Form Group in Angular-2

Tags: javascript, angular, types, angular2-forms

I have two forms first is parent. (I referred https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2) nested form tut.

In first forms fields in a field I am pushing an another form (to achieve multiple filters)

as: searchForm is my first form and addresses is an formarray

```
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
        addresses: this.fb.array([]),
    });
```

Now I am using another form to be pushed in address based on user input. In first form html I am creating second form html as:

```
<div formArrayName="addresses">
    <div *ngFor="let address of searchForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span>Filter {{i + 1}}</span>
            <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" *ngIf="searchForm.controls.addresses.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)"><u>Close</u></a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
            <address [group]="searchForm.controls.addresses.controls[i]"></address>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: when I am creating `<address>` I am passing [group]="searchForm.controls.addresses.controls[i] so is there a way to retrieve it in second form HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could pass it to your address component (like you do with group) using the [@Input() decorator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)?

`<address [index]="i" [group]="searchForm.controls.addresses.controls[i]"></address>`

And in your address component:

```
@Input()
public index: number;
```